# React Native -- FlatList show only last item of pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, pagination, react-native-flatlist

I am using  a FlatList in which I am implementing pagination. When user go to footer of list it hits API and I add the data in existing array. All works fine when user goes to footer and hit API then new data will be added to old data and complete data shows in list for a minute and then suddenly old data vanished and new data left in list only.

**API Code**

```
 const getCards = () => {
const token = JWTToken('');

var axios = require('axios');
var data = JSON.stringify({
  userName: userName.toLocaleLowerCase(),
  userEmail: email,
  userId: userId,
  channel: userSelectedChannel,
  rangeKey: lastKey,
});

// console.log('data feed ', data);
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: BASE_URL + GET_CARDS,
  headers: {
    'x-jwt-token': token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: data,
};

axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    setLoader(false);

    const res = response.data.message;
    setCount(count + 1);

    if (res.hasOwnProperty('LastEvaluatedKey')) {
      const lastEvaluatedKey =
        response.data.message.LastEvaluatedKey.createdAt;

      console.log('last key', lastEvaluatedKey);
      setLastKey(lastEvaluatedKey);
    } else {
      setLastKey('');
    }

    setFeed([...feedArray, ...response.data.message.Items]);

    // addDataTolocalStorage()
    // setFeed(response.data.message.Items);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('feed error', error);
    setLoader(false);
    Alert.alert('Oops!Something went wrong');
  });
};

const handleOnEndReached = async () => {
console.log('count is', count);

if (lastKey !== '' || (lastKey === '' && count === 1)) {
  setLoadingMore(true);
  if (!stopFetchMore) {
    console.log('calling pagination cards');
    getCards();

    stopFetchMore = true;
    setLoadingMore(false);
  }

  // console.log('evaluadted response', response);
}
};
```

**FlatList Render**

```
<FlatList
          data={feedArray}
          renderItem={({item, index}) => (
            <RenderCard
              item={item}
              navigation={navigation}
              index={index}
              managePost={false}
              isPaymentReport={false}
              isBookmark={false}
              previewMode={false}
              isPinnedPost={false}
            />
          )}
          numColumns={1}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            marginBottom: height * 0.1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          }}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
          bounces={false}
          onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
          onScrollBeginDrag={() => {
            stopFetchMore = false;
          }}
          ListFooterComponent={() => loadingMore && <ListFooterComponent />}
        />
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may replace this line

```
onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}
```

to

```
onEndReached={() => handleOnEndReached()}
```

because issue is when you write like this `onEndReached={handleOnEndReached}`
it calls everytime wheather it reached at the end or not.